# write to /sys/bus/pci/drivers/uio_pci_generic/bind is failing

Tags: ubuntu, dpdk, ovs-dpdk

root@prab:/usr/src/dpdk-stable-22.11.1/usertools# echo sh -c  0000:51:00.0 > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/uio_pci_generic/bind
bash: echo: write error: No such device
root@prab:/usr/src/dpdk-stable-22.11.1/usertools# sudo echo sh -c  0000:51:00.0 > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/uio_pci_generic/bind
echo: write error: No such device
root@prab:/usr/src/dpdk-stable-22.11.1/usertools#

root@prab:/usr/src/dpdk-stable-22.11.1/usertools# lsmod | grep uio_pci_generic
uio_pci_generic        16384  0
uio                    20480  1 uio_pci_generic
root@prab:/usr/src/dpdk-stable-22.11.1/usertools#

root@prab:/usr/src/dpdk-stable-22.11.1/usertools# lspci -v -s 0000:51:00.0
51:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller X710 for 10GbE SFP+ (rev 02)

root@prab:/usr/src/dpdk-stable-22.11.1/usertools# echo sh -c  0000:51:00.0 > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/uio_pci_generic/bind
bash: echo: write error: No such device
root@prab:/usr/src/dpdk-stable-22.11.1/usertools# sudo echo sh -c  0000:51:00.0 > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/uio_pci_generic/bind
echo: write error: No such device
root@prab:/usr/src/dpdk-stable-22.11.1/usertools#

Tried running the script dpdk-devbind.py, that also fails due to the abive reason

root@prab:/usr/src/dpdk-stable-22.11.1/usertools# ./dpdk-devbind.py --status

## ...
...
...
Other Network devices

0000:51:00.0 'Ethernet Controller X710 for 10GbE SFP+ 1572' unused=i40e,vfio-pci,uio_pci_generic

I am using the following versions :

root@prab:/usr/src/dpdk-stable-22.11.1/usertools# uname -a
Linux prab 5.15.0-60-generic #66-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 20 14:29:49 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@prab:/usr/src/dpdk-stable-22.11.1/usertools#

root@prab:/usr/src/dpdk-stable-22.11.1/usertools# pkg-config --modversion libdpdk
22.11.1
root@prab:/usr/src/dpdk-stable-22.11.1/usertools#

Answer (score 2):

I do not know what `sh -c` means in your command.

A `bind` in fact needs two write actions: (for kernel > 3.15)

`echo uio_pci_generic > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:51:00.0/driver_override`

`echo 0000:51:00.0 > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/uio_pci_generic/bind`

Also it should work only after `unbind` in previous action.

Why don't you use `dpdk-devbind.py -b uio_pci_generic 0000:51:00.0` . This script has been developed for this purpose.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. Initially i tried running the dpdk-devbind.py. But that script is also failing with the same reason :  

Error: bind failed for 0000:51:00.0 - Cannot bind to driver uio_pci_generic: [Errno 19] No such device
                                                                                    

When i run the script, the unbind happens successfully and the drivers are shown as unused :


Other Network devices
=====================
0000:51:00.0 'Ethernet Controller X710 for 10GbE SFP+ 1572' unused=i40e,vfio-pci,uio_pci_generic

Comment: After this step, script calls, device override. That is also successful :

 cat /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:51:00.0/driver_override
uio_pci_generic


After this step, the script tries to append the bind file. Thats where it fails with the following reason :


Error: bind failed for 0000:51:00.0 - Cannot bind to driver uio_pci_generic: [Errno 19] No such device

Since the script failed, i tried the same step manually. And that where i got this error :

echo 0000:51:00.0 > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/uio_pci_generic/bind
bash: echo: write error: No such device

Comment: then have a try for this，   sudo sh -c "echo 0000:51:00.0 > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/uio_pci_generic/bind"

Comment: tried doing that as well. It is not working.

Comment: have you tried any other uio drivers? like vfio-pci, igb_uio, etc. Some devices may fail for part of these drivers.